# Nothing happens when I call my print method on a thread off the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a `method` that does some printing and I want the task to run on another thread (not on the EDT) because it might be creating a large file and I dont want the long process to freeze the GUI. The execution works perfectly on the EDT (with GUI freezing of course - which isn't desired), but when invoked on a different thread, it just doesn't execute. 
Here goes the method;

```
                    buildReceipt(itemList, method);
```

Where;

- `itemList` is an ArrayList used to populate the receipt, and
- `method` is an `enum` Type that determines whether to make the output a .pdf File or Send it directly to a Printer

The code above produces the document nicely when executed on the EDT but when I tried making it a background task using `doInBackground()` method of `SwingWorker` , it just didn't do anything at all; Then I got curious and tried the following;

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        buildReceipt(itemList, method);
    }
});
thread.start();
```

and still, nothing happened......... More funny and confusing is the fact that I have even tried `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` & `SwingUtilities.InvokeAndWait` (which by documentation run on the EDT) but still to no avail.
I have searched as many Stack Overflow related questions as I could, but none addresses my strange problem. I really need help on this one. Been stuck since yesteray?!?!?!

### EDIT:

In Respose to Jean Waghetti; here's briefly what happens inside `buildReceipt`

```
private boolean buildReceipt(ArrayList<Sales> itemList, PrintMethod method)
{
    boolean built = false;
    if(!itemList.isEmpty())
    {
        InvoiceDesign design = new InvoiceDesign(itemList);
        try 
        {
            JasperReportBuilder report = design.build();

            if(method.equals(PrintMethod.PDF))
            {
                appManager.connectToDB();
                File fileDir = appManager.getReceiptsDir();
                appManager.disconnectDB();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileDir);
                report.toPdf(fos);
                fos.close();
                built = true;
            }
            else if(method.equals(PrintMethod.PRINTER))
            {
                report.print(true);
                built = true;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (DRException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return built;
}
```

Comment: Can you put some debug statement in run() to confirm that the method is indeed called?

Comment: What does buildReceipt method do? Please, post more of your code to us.

Comment: `ArrayList` is not thread safe (use `Vector` to easily fix that) and your `Sales` object should be immutable if you want to avoid issues. I would stick a break point at the entrance of your method and inspect `itemsList`

Comment: @Sudhanshu, In my SwingWorker's doInBackground() thread, I put a `System.out.println("Got here")` after `buildReceipt`. Then I also put a `System.out.println("Bingo")` inside the `buildReceipt` method's `finally` block. The only output I got was "Got here". So it seems to me like the `buildReceipt` method is absolutely being skipped, no?

Comment: Please put SOP in run() as well.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Thanks for giving me such time. I really appreciate... Ok I put the S.o.p inside `run()` too, and I got the output "Got here", but didn't get the "Bingo" from inside `buildReceipt`

Comment: I suspect that the item list is empty, cannot think of any other reason now. Please print the size of item list at the start of buildReceipt().

Comment: @BGR thanks for your fine suggestion. I get everything except the 'immutable' part. what does it mean? How do I implement that?

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). The java memory model is complex. Follow simple rules described in this doc when in a multithreaded environment (until you become one of the rare black belts)

Comment: @Sudhanshu WoooW!... I cant believe I didn't even think about that, cos that's exactly what's happening at the entrance of `buildReceipt` `itemList.size()` returned `0`. I'm heading over to fix this A-S-A-P! Thanks Billions! I guess I was too close to the codes to see that! +100 if i could!

Comment: @BGR I'll be consumed in that document, I must tell you. Thanks for the pointer. Very essential knowledge now that i ventured into multithreading... I really appreciate Sire!

Comment: @Teejay Good that you got the root cause. Just put it into the answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your item list is empty hence it never executes the code in the IF condition in that method.

Comment: Yes, the `itemList` was empty by the time it got to my `SwingWorker`'s background thread. Thanks to YOU for pointing me to it... So basically, I resolved the issue by using a `Vector` (Thanks to @BGR) to pass my Collection arguments around the various threads due to `Vector`'s thread-safeness (as opposed to the `ArrayList` that I was using before)... and everything became BLISS!!!